# Configuring ArcGIS Online Crowdsource Reporter App?

Tags: arcgis-online, crowdsourcing

Deploying ESRI AGOL Crowdsource Reporter App and even though editable feature layers visible in map frame, and submitted reports are visible with fields, the form to submit a report does not launch with fields present (after click +submit report button, system hangs and never populates form).

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by opening the map and saving it in map viewer classic.